# Plans for more sequels to Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas, sequel

Does George Lucas have any plans for more *Star Wars* sequels or prequels? Proper movie sequels, not any supplementary animated shows or stories.

Comment: Maybe after Lucas becomes one with the Force

Comment: In light of the changes post-acquisition by Disney, you may wish to reconsider your acceptance of @billthelizards' (now incorrect) answer.

Comment: Yes, apparently Lucas did have plans for Star Wars VII but Disney have chosen to go a different route; https://uk.yahoo.com/movies/george-lucas-reveals-his-star-wars-vii-script-was-108727363214.html

Comment: @Richard Can an answer be "unaccepted"?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - Yes, just click the accept button again.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the advice. Didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When this question was originally asked, it looked like George Lucas *didn't* have any plans to make any more Star Wars films. That hasn't changed, but we all now know that the franchise was [sold to Disney](http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/business/2012/10/30/disney-star-wars-lucasfilm/1669739/), Episode VII has been released, and more Star Wars films and series are on the way.

---

Original answer:

Unfortunately it doesn't seem likely.  Here's a quote from an interview he gave in 2008.  (The article is [Will Lucas Extend His 'Star Wars' Story Beyond 'Return of the Jedi'?](http://blog.moviefone.com/2008/05/07/will-lucas-extend-his-star-wars-story-past-return-of-the-je/))

> "There really isn't any story to tell there. It's been covered in the books and video games and comic books, which are things I think are incredibly creative but that I don't really have anything to do with other than being the person who built the sandbox they're playing in." He continues, "I get asked all the time, 'What happens after "Return of the Jedi"?,' and there really is no answer for that. The movies were the story of Anakin Skywalker and Luke Skywalker, and when Luke saves the galaxy and redeems his father, that's where that story ends."

Comment: Gary Kurtz, who produced Episodes IV and V with Lucas, left before Episode VI.  He said when Lucas started he had an outline that would have provided wonderful entertainment for a number of trilogies and they could have gone on for years, but Lucas started changing everything.  Originally it was "From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker" (I have a paperback "Star Wars" 1st printing with that on the cover), but then after ESB, Lucas got absorbed in changing it all and making it archetypal and mythic.  That changed the story line and killed the original sequel plans.

Comment: “There really isn't any story to tell there.” Ha! That’ll look great on a Star Wars VII poster.

Comment: Not sure if I should downvote this, since it was right at the time.

Comment: @DCShannon I knew there was something I was forgetting to do! :)

Comment: And now I'll upvote it.

Comment: It's funny that the original answer said that it was unfortunate we wouldn't get sequels, but now that we have them we know that the unfortunate thing is that we did get them.

Answer (score 32):

With the recently concluded (November 2012) [acquisition of Lucasfilm](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/kidspost/disney-and-lucasfilm-unite-superheroes-and-popular-cartoon-characters/2012/11/08/8f0ca2a8-252e-11e2-ac85-e669876c6a24_story.html) by the Walt Disney Co., Disney is planning to release Episode VII of the Star Wars saga in 2015.

> "Our long-term plan is to release a new 'Star Wars' feature film every two to three years," said Disney's Robert Iger.

George Lucas will not be directing the new films; he is retiring.

> "It's now time for me to pass 'Star Wars' on to a new generation of filmmakers," he said.

EDIT: Plans for the new film have firmed up, with J. J. Abrams signed on as director and Abrams and Lawrence Kasdan to do the screenwriting.  John Williams will return to score *Episode VII*.  Shooting is expected to begin in the spring of 2014 and the film is scheduled to hit theaters 18 December 2015.  Source [starwars.com](http://starwars.com/news/episode-vii-news/).

Comment: You may wish to edit in the info about George Lucas' scripts being rejected by Disney; https://uk.yahoo.com/movies/george-lucas-reveals-his-star-wars-vii-script-was-108727363214.html

Answer (score 12):

Ther's is still rumor that there will be a sequel trilogy.
Here the [last one I'm aware of](http://io9.com/5671581/george-lucas-reported-creating-new-star-wars-sequel-trilogy-thats-not-about-the-skywalkers) :

> [...] fans can expect the
>   new trilogy after the entire saga is
>   released in 3D which is expected to be
>   complete around 2015 or 2016.

Comment: Okay, here's the plan... **Nobody** buy the *Episode I: 3D* release so Lucas scraps the rest of that project and moves the sequel trilogy up by 5 years.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - I'll raise you, nobody buy into anymore 3D because it's a fad that I hope passes soon

Comment: @Brenton Taylor I agree, my wife has 3D sickness and finding a theater that don't show the last sf movie in 2d is difficult.

Comment: The link to back up the rumour now goes to a site for "Wholesale Construction Specialties", which may be appropriate.

Comment: @DJClayworth I tried to find the original link on wayback.archive.org, but no luck. I updated the answer with a link that refer (and quote) it.

Answer (score 7):

Technically, George Lucas doesn't plan on making any more films, as he sold the rights.

However, Disney has multiple *Star Wars* films [planned](http://www.denofgeek.us/movies/star-wars/241723/full-star-wars-movie-release-calendar), with set release dates.

The first, *[Star Wars: Episode VII: The Force Awakens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/)* came out December 18, 2015.

The next, *[Rogue One](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/)* will come out December 16, 2016.

Comment: Except Lucas turned in an early script for Ep 7. He *had* plans for at least one more film.

Answer (score 4):

Many years ago, I got a chance to talk to Anthony Daniels at a [Gen Con](http://www.gencon.com/). I specifically asked him about the chance of episodes 7, 8, and 9, which Lucas originally had planned to make.

Daniels told me it wouldn't happen.